# Setting permission to write apex classes

Tags: apex, permissions, developer-console

I am working on a visual force page, and have reached a point where I need a custom controller to accomplish what I want.  When I open up the developer console, and attempt to "open execute anonymous window" (Ctrl+E) I get an error message that says:

> You don't have the permission to execute Apex

How can I change this?  In a similar question here I saw that I need to set my "Author Apex" permission under "Administrative Permissions", however I cannot find Administrative Permission settings.  Note that I have a System Administrator profile using Salesforce Profession edition.

Edit:
The core issue is that I need the ability to execute Apex. Not necessarily using the developer console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Professional Edition can only execute Apex code if that code is in a managed package that has passed the security review. No other Apex code will run, regardless of whether it is from the console.

See details here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm

Comment: Thanks Neo, I saw that, but I didn't think that applied to my situation.  I'm not trying to write an app, I just need a little bit more than what the standard controller gives me in a VF page.

Comment: @TheGilbertArenasDagger - Apex code is apex code regardless of what it is used for. Unfortunately, you are not able to do it with your edition

Answer (score 2):

Developer console not available in Profession Edition.

Using the Developer Console Available in:

**Available in: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, Developer, and Database.com Editions**

Comment: Thanks for the response, is it just the developer console that I do not have access to, or am I limited in executing Apex code in general?

Comment: If you are using Profession edition, then its not available. See this https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_system_log.htm

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty clear that the professional edition isn't supported by the developer console, but I didn't see anything that said I can't execute Apex code at all in my edition.  I need to look into this more, but I am under the impression that the developer console was just one way to execute Apex.  I plan to accept your answer soon, I'm just trying to figure out if it's I cannot execute custom apex code under any circumstances, or if I just need to use something other than the developer console.